# Question regarding permutation groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here's the question:

> Suppose $\alpha$ is a cycle of length of $s$, say $\alpha
> =(a_1a_2a_3\dots a_s)$. Now, if $s$ is a multiple of $k$, say $s=kt$ then show that $\alpha ^{k}$ is the product of $k$ cycles of length $t$.

Here is my scratch work. Consider $\alpha ^s$. Then $\alpha^s = \alpha ^{kt}$. Hence, $(\alpha^{k})^{t}=\text{id}$.

I also notice that if $\alpha^k$ were a product of $k$ **disjoint** cycles of length $t$ say $\alpha^k = (a_{11} a_{12} \dots a_{1t})(a_{21}a_{22}\dots a_{2t})\dots (a_{k1} a_{k2}\dots a_{kt})$ then since, we know that order of any cycle is its length, we could conclude $\alpha^{kt}=\text{id}$.

Well, can I get hints? I don't need the solution though.

Comment: You are almost done. Let $\alpha^k = (a_{11} a_{12} \dots a_{1t_1})(a_{21}a_{22}\dots a_{2t_2})\dots (a_{r1} a_{r2}\dots a_{rt_r})$ be the product of disjoint cycles.

Comment: @8k14 However, the product of cycles does not necessarily have to be disjoint.

Comment: Any permutation is the product of disjoint cycles

Comment: @8k14 In this case, I assumed whatever I had to prove though. I assumed $\alpha^k $ is a product of k cycles and it does not necessarily have to be.

Comment: Another way: $a^k=(a_1a_{k+1}\ldots)(a_2a_{k+2}\ldots)\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

Just reason on how this cycle acts. For the sake of simplicity assume $\alpha = (0 \ldots s-1) $. You have $\alpha(x) =x+1 \pmod s$, thus $\alpha^k(x) = x+k \pmod{s} $. As you noticed, every cycle length must divide $t$, because $(\alpha^k) ^t=id$. On the other hand, for $p<t$ you have $(\alpha^k) ^p(x) =x+pk \pmod{s} $, which doesn't equal $x$. In conclusion, every cycle has *exactly* length $t$.